# OpenMP Crashing with Large Arrays

Tags: fortran, openmp, fortran90, gfortran

I'm using Fortran and OpenMP, but I keep encountering an issue when I try to parallelize loops using OpenMP when there are large arrays. For example, the following code:

```
PROGRAM main
IMPLICIT NONE   
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: NUMLOOPS = 300000
REAL(8) :: TESTMAT(NUMLOOPS)
INTEGER :: i,j

!$OMP PARALLEL SHARED(TESTMAT)
!$OMP DO
DO i=1,NUMLOOPS         
    TESTMAT(i) = i
END DO
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL

write(*,*) SUM(TESTMAT)/(NUMLOOPS)

END PROGRAM main
```

compiled using this Makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES: .f90

F90 = gfortran
FFLAGS_PFM = -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none -fopenmp
LIB = -llapack
OBJ90 = main.o 

main: $(OBJ90)
    $(F90) $(FFLAGS_PFM) -o $@ $(LIB) $(OBJ90)

${OBJ90}: %.o: %.f90
    $(F90) $(FFLAGS_PFM) $(LIB) -c -o $@ $<
```

Crashes when on a windows machine, compiled using gfortran. However, if I change the NUMLOOPS value to anything less than around 260000, the program runs just fine. Similarly, a matrix of about 1000x1000 would crash (anything above around 500x500, in fact, doesn't work). Thus, it seems like there is a maximum array size allowed when using OpenMP? I haven't come across anything of this kind though. I've tried on multiple windows machines, with the same result, however all use the same configuration, e.g. Windows 7 with gfortran compiler. The code always compiles without issue, but crashes when run.

Answer (score 4):

Specifying `-fopenmp` in GNU Fortran implies `-frecursive` which means that all local variables (even large arrays) are automatic (i.e. allocated on the stack). On Windows the stack size is fixed in the PE executable header file and has to be specified during link phase, very much unlike on Unix systems where it can be dynamically controlled by the limits mechanism.

To increase the stack size of your Windows executable you can either use `editbin.exe` from Microsoft with a command line like:

```
editbin /STACK:<size> yourexe.exe
```

or supply the following option to GCC: `-Wl,--stack,<size in bytes>`, where `<size in bytes>` is the desired stack size in bytes. You should set the stack size at least large enough to fit the whole array (that is `8*NUMLOOPS`) and the local variables and stuff.

Answer (score 3):

OpenMP does not impose any limits on the size of arrays that you can instantiate.  Your Fortran compiler might; check the documentation for that.

The hardware you are using does impose a limit -- you won't be able to declare an array which has an index value larger than HUGE(int) on your machine; since HUGE(int) is likely to be either (2^31)-1 or (2^63)-1 (Fortran does not have unsigned integers) this is probably not affecting you at the moment.

The other limit, which may be affecting you, is that there is likely to be a limit to the size of a variable that your compiler will let you declare.  I'm not familiar with gfortran, but I suggest you Google around or look in the documentation.  It may be that there is a limit on the size of stack that gfortran can handle, on many platforms Fortran variables which are declared statically (i.e. are not ALLOCATABLE) will be placed on a stack.  I suspect that this is the root of your problem.

If you can't persuade your compiler to let you declare a larger array at compile time, try making the array ALLOCATABLE and allocating it at run time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Making TESTMAT allocatable does in fact work! However, I'm still curious as to why this is occuring in the first place. I guess I forgot to mention that the code above works if I remove the OpenMP bits, i.e. the OMP declarations, and the -fopenmp flag in the makefile, so the behaviour seems specific to gfortran+openmp. But either way, a step forward, thanks again!

Comment: It might be, that with the OpenMP version, the compiler puts the array on the stack instead of a static location in the executable, in this case you might get around the problem also by unlimiting the stack size, typically achieved with a "ulimit -s unlimited".

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. As far as I understand the option -fopenmp came by default with -frecursive. This latter force large array to be in a stack and that is our probelm.

A pseudo-solution is to overwrites the -frecursive option implied by the -fopenmp using another option against it. For this I add the option -fno-automatic for gfortran compiler option

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution in comparison to my previous one that consists in inserting, before running your code the following cmd: `ulimit -s unlimited`. This in order to get rid of the default limitation on stack size.